# Backup to two harddrives simultaneously

Tags: backup

I was wondering if there was a way of backing up the files from one hard drive, to two or three other hard drives simultaneously (connections will be over FireWire and be done off a laptop), so that there is only one read to two writes?

I was thinking about a custom bash script something like

```
cat /location/to/file/a.ext | tee /backupharddrive/location/to/file/a.ext > /backupharddriveb/location/to/file/a.ext
```

but it seemed to be of the same performance as if I were to copy them separately

Comment: This is more of a superuser kind of question.

Comment: Try using two bash scripts (one to each drive); or, RAID.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [RSync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/)?

Pseudo Code (not guaranteed to be accurate at all!)

```
foreach hard_drive_device
     rsync source_dir $hard_drive_device/dest_dir
fi
```

Granted this is not asynchronous but would achieve your task. 
You could put a & at the end if you want to fork the process into the background

Or using the old hacker philosophy: scratch your own itch!

You could create a program in your favourite language called multicopy that takes one read source and then writes to many destinations

Pseudo Code (not guaranteed to be accurate at all!)

```
if(src is directory)
  for each file in directory
    CopyFile(file, destList)
  fi
else
  CopyFile(src, destList)
fi

CopyFile(src, destList) {
 foreach block in src
    foreach dest in destList
        open(dest/src)
        seek(end)
        write(block)
    fi
 fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The setup requires separate hard drives... not raid configurations...